# When querying the linked server throws an error 'Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction.'

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

When I am querying the linked server like `select * from [servername].[DBname].[schema].[tablename]` it throws an error

> 'Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped
>   this transaction'

But when i run query like `select * from openquery([servername],'myquery')` it works fine.

So what is the difference between both the query, why it run for 2nd and not the first.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118250/four-part-distributed-query-issue-from-2014-to-2008r2